# Radiation of visible light from LC circuit

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

Can we get a visible radiation from LC circuit as it produces e.m.radiation when charge oscillates in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an LC oscillator be used to generate visible light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122474/)

Comment: Do you mean, "Can we practically create a circuit with L and C so tiny that the oscillation frequency is that of visible light?", or do you mean, "Can we make a circuit with, for example, an LED that lights up when it detects energy in the LC circuit?"?