# Light is a high frequency electromagnetic wave. Can an LC oscillation circuit emit visible light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

As we all know, light is a kind of high-frequency electromagnetic waves. Can *LC* oscillation circuit emit visible light?

Comment: Duplicate of [Can an LC oscillator be used to generate visible light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122474/140996)

Answer (score 1):

As you say, light is a high frequency electromagnetic wave. The frequency is so high that an array of submicron LC circuits is required. Such circuits exist and they belong to a class of materials called [photonic metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_metamaterial) .